# How to set umask in UNIX in a way that default file permission is rwx (777)?

Tags: unix, umask

I am a bit new to UNIX and I'm trying to cover every aspect of a group of basic commands, including `umask`.

I have done a lot of research on the internet but haven't found a proper answer so far, I know that files are created by default with a 666 (rw-,rw-,rw-) permission and I know that in order to get the real permissions applied you need to take into consideration the `umask`.

I would like to know if it's possible to set `umask` in a way that files are created with a 777 (rwx,rwx,rwx) permission. If not possible with the `umask` command, then how can I do it?

I already know about chmod but that means using it every time a new file is created, something I don't want.

Comment: I quickly read the docs and I think you need `umask 0`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that means the default file permission will be set to 666, I have already tried it.

Comment: To add on the above comment, it's folders permissions which would be 777 if the mask was 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, there is no guarantee you can make that. Longer version in this detailed post:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287278/why-doesnt-umask-change-execute-permissions-on-files

Comment: Actually, that means it's not possible unless I rewrite the touch command. I'll just stick with 666 for now, thanks for the answer/link.